# Typo3: Put modules of different extensions in one Module group in the typo3 backend module list

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

Currently I'm trying to create a module group in the typo3 backend module list on the left hand side. My group works fine for modules within the same extension. But when I try to add modules from other extensions to it, it simply doesn't work.

I have created this Module group (`mainmodule`) in the `ext_tables.php` file in one of my other extensions like this:

`/**
        * Creates a Backend Module Category
        */
       $GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES'] = array_slice($GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES'], 0, 1, true) +
           ['mainmodule' => ''] +
           array_slice($GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES'], 1, count($GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES']) - 1, true);
       $GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES']['_configuration']['mainmodule'] = [
           'iconIdentifier' => 'module',
           'labels' => 'LLL:EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_myExt.xlf:mlang_key',
           'name' => 'mainmodule',
       ];`

I'm trying to use the mainmodule in a different extension as follows:

`\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule(
               'VEN.' . $extKey,
               'mainmodule',     // Make module a submodule of 'mainmodule'
               'randomkey',    // Submodule key
               '',
...`

The module is always created inside its "own" mainmodule.

I have tried all of the solutions given here on stackoverflow and spent hours of trying to solve this issue. I just can't get it to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems other extensions are loaded before this extensions which defines the new backend module category. So `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerModule` will fail because of the missing category. To check this have a look at the loading order of the extensions in `typo3conf/PackageStates.php`.

To resolve the issue, add this extension to the `constraint` in `ext_em.conf` and `require` in `composer.json` to force it's loaded before the other extensions with the dependency to the new backend module category. See https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/DeclarationFile/Index.html and https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/ComposerJson/Index.html.

Other solution could be adding the new category in each extension if it does not already exist.